# FindBugs says I need to "use a prepared statement"? How?

Tags: java, jdbc, findbugs

I ran FindBugs and this is the bug at line 2.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE menu set menu.name'"
                                + value2 + "', menu.info'" + value3
                                + "', menu.price'" + value4
                                + "' where menu.menuID='" + value1 + "'");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2,
                                "Updated successfully");
                        con.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2,
                                "Error in updating edit fields");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2, "Error");
            }
        }
    });
```

I ran FindBugs and this is the bug at line 2.

> Bug: ie.lyit.flight.Changeadd$5.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) passes a nonconstant String to an execute or addBatch method on an SQL statement
>   The method invokes the execute or addBatch method on an SQL statement with a String that seems to be dynamically generated. Consider using a prepared statement instead. It is more efficient and less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
>
> Rank: Troubling (10), confidence: High
>   Pattern: SQL_NONCONSTANT_STRING_PASSED_TO_EXECUTE 
>   Type: SQL, Category: SECURITY (Security)

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get rid of this bug and how I would go about doing it?

Comment: Maybe by "using a prepared statement instead"? Can you be more specific as to what is your problem in detail?

Comment: yes and how would I fix my could by doing so and using a prepared statement

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Did you do any research on how to solve the problem yourself, such as Googling "Java prepared statement"?

Answer (score 3):

See [the JDBC tutorial on using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

In this case, this might look something like:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE menu set menu.name=?, menu.info=?, menu.price=? where menu.menuID=?")
stmt.setString(1, value2); /* menu.name */
stmt.setString(2, value3); /* menu.info */
stmt.setFloat(3, value4);  /* menu.price */
stmt.setInt(4, value1);    /* menuID */
stmt.executeUpdate();
```